# simple java multiplication game

Tags: java

I'm making a simple multiplication game, but when the user enters a correct answer, it still runs the `else` statement. I know it's a simple solution but I just can't figure it out. Can someone give me a hand?

```
public static void partB() {
    System.out.println("Exercise 1B");
    int count = 0;
    String active = "true";
    int correct = 0;
    while (active == "true") {
        Random r = new Random();
        int Low = 10; //inclusive
        int High = 21; //not inclusive
        int Result = r.nextInt(High - Low) + Low;
        Random r2 = new Random();
        int Result2 = r2.nextInt(High - Low) + Low;
        int Total = Result * Result2;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(Result + "*" + Result2 + "=?");
        String guess = new String(input.nextLine());
        String tostrng = String.valueOf(Total);

        if (guess.equals (tostrng)) {
            correct += 1;
            count+=1;
            System.out.println("Correct answer. Score: " + correct + "(" + count + ")"); 
        }
        if (guess.equals("q")) {
            System.out.println("Good Bye!");
            active = "false";
            //return;
        }
        else {
            count +=1;
            System.out.println("Incorrect answer. Score:" + correct + "(" + count + ")");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `else if (guess.equals("q"))`

Comment: Please stick to java naming conventions. Variable names should always start with a lower case character. So `low` and `high` etc. After that you should use camelCase.

Comment: sorry, been learning python for the last year so it became a habit i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your else with wrong if

```
public static void partB() {
    System.out.println("Exercise 1B");
    int count = 0;
    String active = "true";
    int correct = 0;
    while (active == "true") {
        Random r = new Random();
        int Low = 10; //inclusive
        int High = 21; //not inclusive
        int Result = r.nextInt(High - Low) + Low;
        Random r2 = new Random();
        int Result2 = r2.nextInt(High - Low) + Low;
        int Total = Result * Result2;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(Result + "*" + Result2 + "=?");
        String guess = new String(input.nextLine());
        String tostrng = String.valueOf(Total);

        if (guess.equals (tostrng)) {
            correct += 1;
            count+=1;
            System.out.println("Correct answer. Score: " + correct + "(" + count + ")");
        }
       else {
            count +=1;
            System.out.println("Incorrect answer. Score:" + correct + "(" + count + ")");
        }
        if (guess.equals("q")) {
            System.out.println("Good Bye!");
            active = "false";
            //return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If it's working for you, you have to mark this answer accepted and create new question for any other help

Answer (score 0):

Make type of active variable as boolean i.e.  boolean active=true;
and for comparing string values always use .equals() method.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it like this!
thanks for the help though guys.

```
if (guess.equals("q")) {
    System.out.println("Good Bye!");

    return;
}

if (guess.equals(tostrng)) {
    correct += 1;
    count += 1;

    System.out.println("Correct answer. Score: " + correct + "(" + count + ")");
} else {
    count += 1;

    System.out.println("Incorrect answer. Score:" + correct + "(" + count + ")");
}
```

Comment: an else if /like ruhul sugested) would still be the better solution. Your solution is a bit shaky imho, since if you move the statements into another order it will fail again. But if the logical decision tree grows more complex (e.g. pause the game, give a hint,...) you can easily forget that you have to be careful with these if statements.